# Spring security with weblogic server

Tags: authentication, spring-security

I have a spring mvc application which is build with spring security for authentication. It works perfectly fine when deployed with jetty server. All the request gets authenticated properly with the in memory users created in spring security configuration.

When I deploy the same application on weblogic server to authenticate with the users created on weblogic server, authentication no more works. It doesn't prompt for username and password. I expect my application to authenticate with the users created on weblogic server, but it doesn't work.

I know I am missing an important link between spring and weblogic server integration. I could not find any working example which will help me establish that link.

It would be good if somebody helps me with the sample code which tells how to configure spring security with weblogic server.

Thanks in advace

/Ganesh

Comment: No error. I do not see any error in log. It simply doesn't authenticate.

Comment: Found the solution to the problem. Got it working with the help of https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/preauth-xml